# Drawing QPixmap Rects Over QWidget with QPainter

Tags: qt, drawing, qpixmap

I'll get serialized `QPixmap` `Rect`s over the socket. I'll unserialize them and draw the rects in a `QWidget` Now my question is which `QWidget`  should I use for this purpose ? is there any recontamination about how should I proceed ? at the moment I've decided to use a `QPainter` and draw using `drawPixmap` am I going in a wrong direction ?

Comment: Need more information ... what are you *doing* with the drawn pixmaps? Is the primary purpose a graphics application, or do you want the pixmaps to become the background of a form with other widgets on it, or what? As your question is stated, it is hard to give a recommendation.

Comment: Are you drawing pixmaps AND rectangles, or pixmaps in the rectangles? And if later, are the rectangles the destination for the pixmaps, or the parts in the pixmaps that are to be drawn?

Comment: No actually This is a Screen Sharing App. one end is sending the Screen Shot rectangles they are being drawn on the viewer screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you might want use `QGraphicsPixmapItem` instances drawn on a `QGraphicsScene` with a `QGraphicsView`.

See [Qt Graphics View Framework](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/graphicsview.html):

> Graphics View provides a surface for
>   managing and interacting with a large
>   number of custom-made 2D graphical
>   items, and a view widget for
>   visualizing the items, with support
>   for zooming and rotation.
>
> The framework includes an event
>   propagation architecture that allows
>   precise double-precision interaction
>   capabilities for the items on the
>   scene. Items can handle key events,
>   mouse press, move, release and double
>   click events, and they can also track
>   mouse movement.
>
> Graphics View uses a BSP (Binary Space
>   Partitioning) tree to provide very
>   fast item discovery, and as a result
>   of this, it can visualize large scenes
>   in real-time, even with millions of
>   items.

Comment: But I dont need support for zooming and rotation for individual Item. Nither these Items are unique. they are all similer Rectangles. same in size and same in color Information too.

Comment: Any painting surface you use is going to come with a lot of stuff you might not use. The graphics framework does let you turn off some of these things so you don't pay for what you don't need. If it's not fast enough, you may want to use OpenGL (http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/qtopengl.html). But the graphics framework will be a *lot* simpler.